# ActionScript 3 not working (Flash CS5)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I was recently trying to help a friend get started with Flash, and ran into a very weird bug. It looks like AS3 isn't being evaluated. Something as simple as a trace statement on the first frame of the movie doesn't produce any output. When I switch over to AS2, the trace statement works. What's going on here? Is it a problem with his Flash installation?

Comment: I had a similar problem once, for me it was the directory the project was in. It had been in something like the root directory of my C:\ which caused the problems.

Comment: I've run into a similar issue on my Mac--certain folder names throw Flash for a loop and I got a lot of class-not-found type of errors. It was actually really odd, in that it would not recognized only select classes, including all the ones where the class name started with "D". :-/

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that AS3 isn't working. More likely you forgot to re-build the program (you might also need to close any open instances of the program for this to work successfully), or you don't have an up-to-date installation of Flash. I would certainly try both rebuilding as well as downloading/installing a newer version of  [Flash Player](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) before concluding that AS3 was broken. If that doesn't work, feel free to update this post with an example snippet of code (it's hard to debug the code otherwise). Good luck.